# How to create a DATABASE LINK between two H2 databases?

Tags: database, h2, database-administration

I created two H2 databases and I am unable to link the database. I have achieved to link the databases in ORACLE through CREATE DATABASE LINK. We have similar DB Link in POSTGRES DB also. Do we have any way to link the DATABASE in H2 ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot link the whole database, but you can link individual tables with `CREATE LINKED TABLE` command:
https://h2database.com/html/commands.html#create_linked_table

There is a helper `LINK_SCHEMA` function to create table links for all tables in the specified schema:
https://h2database.com/html/functions.html#link_schema